# Set Defaults and Validate POST Request

Tags: node.js, express

```
var requiredKeys = {title: 'string', src: 'string', length: 'number'};
var optionalKeys = {description: 'string', playcount: 'number', ranking: 'number'};
var internalKeys = {id: 'number', timestamp: 'number'};

// routes **********************
videos.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res, next) {
        res.json(store.select(/json/))
        next();
    })
    .post(function(req, res, next) {
        res.json(store.insert(/json/, {
            description: req.body.description,
            src: req.body.src,
            length: req.body.length,
            playcount: req.body.playcount,            
            ranking: req.body.ranking,
            timestamp: "00:00:00"
        }))
        next()
    })
```

How can i set these variables as Defaults if a field is empty or not given in the POST Request. Also how is a proper way to validate these before i put them in my DB with store.insert() ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Joi` library - to add it just type: `yarn add joi`. `Joi` will validate Your data (in that case `req.body`) against schema (in that case `postSchema`). In the schema, You can use `default(...)` which will allow to to specify default values of the fields (in that case when `title` is not present, it will add `title` filed with value: `default value`. In route method `router.route(...).post(...)` You just invoke `Joi.validate(data, schema)` and wait for the result.

Here is the example code:

```
const Joi = require('joi')
const router = require('express').Router();

const postSchema = {
  title: Joi.string().default('default value'),
  src: Joi.string().default('default src'),
  length: Joi.number().integer().default(0),
}

router.route('/')
  .post(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const schemaValidationResult = await Joi.validate(req.body, postSchema);
      console.log(`schema is valid ${JSON.stringify(schemaValidationResult)}`);
      const { src, title, length } = schemaValidationResult;
      return res.status(200).send({ src, title, length });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`schema is not valid ${error}`);
      return res.status(422).send(error);
    }
  });

module.exports = router;
```